# Python Implementation for MATLAB's getByteStreamFromArray/getArrayFromByteStream

Tags: python, database, matlab, serialization

I am working on an application whose data must be accessible from both Python and MATLAB via a table in a database. The data is a struct that contains matlab arrays.

```
data.sift1 = linspace(-5,5,7)
data.sift2 = linspace(-2,8,7)`
```

The current implementation of the data storing method in MATLAB:

*Saving: Serializing*

```
bs = getByteStreamFromArray(data);
whos bs
% Name: bs Size: 47944x1 Bytes: 47944 Class: uint8
sth.setBytes(1, bs); % sth = database handle
sth.execute;`
```

*Loading: Deserializing*

```
sifts = exec(conn, 'SELECT sifts FROM data LIMIT 1'); % conn = dbconnection instance
siftsmat = typecast(cell2mat(sifts), 'uint8')
% Name: siftsmat Size: 47944x1 Bytes: 47944 Class: uint8
data = getArrayFromByteStream(siftsmat)
% data = sift1: [...] sift2: [...]
```

In python,

*Loading: Deserializing*

```
sifts = conn.select('SELECT sifts FROM data LIMIT 1')
% <read-only buffer for 0x7f175a479a10, size 47944, offset 0 at 0x7f174ce31c70>
b = bytearray(sifts)
siftsmat = struct.unpack('B'*len(b), b)
data = ???`
```

*Saving: Serializing*

```
???
```

I wonder if there is anything in python equivalent to [getByteStreamFromArray/getArrayFromByteStream](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data) in MATLAB so that I can read the `data` written by MATLAB using python.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing. With the MATLAB Engine for Python, you could let MATLAB do the conversion, but that may not be quite what you're looking for. This would require a (licensed) MATLAB on the same machine that your Python code is running on.

Right now that is ok for my use case, but I'll be looking into alternatives soon ;-)

So what I do now is, start a MATLAB Engine from Python, then call getArrayFromByteStream from MATLAB on my Bytestream and then convert it to a NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np
import matlab.engine

# 
# some code that gives you myByteStream
#

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
myNativeArray = eng.getArrayFromByteStream(myByteStream)
myArray = np.array(myNativeArray)
```

More info on this MATLAB Engine for Python: 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/get-started-with-matlab-engine-for-python.html